# Create several Pivot tables on the same sheet c#

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create several pivot tables in the same sheet ,
it works great when I try to create one pivot table , but when I try to create many ones , I'm getting only one (witch is the combination of all pivots and having the name of the last PivotTable ) , here is my code :

assuming that we will populate all pivot tables from the same datasource (same sheet)

```
pivotData is : the range of the source table

name is the name of the sheet where we will create the pivots

  public void CreatePivotTable(Range pivotData, List<string> pivotFields, List<string> aggFields, string pivotPosition, string name)
    {

        var pivotTableName = name;

        var pivotDestination = _worksheet.Range[pivotPosition, UseDefault];

        _workbook.PivotTableWizard(
            XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
            pivotData,
            pivotDestination,
            pivotTableName,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            UseDefault,
            UseDefault,
            false,
            false,
            XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
            0,
            UseDefault,
            UseDefault
            );

        var pivotTable = (PivotTable)_worksheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName);


        foreach (var label in pivotFields.Select(field => ((PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(field))))
        {
            label.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
        }

        foreach (var sumValues in aggFields.Select(field => ((PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(field))))
        {
            sumValues.Orientation =
                XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
            sumValues.Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
        }

        pivotTable.Format(XlPivotFormatType.xlTable2);
        pivotTable.InGridDropZones = false;

    }
```

can any one tell me what i'm messing , how can I get every pivot separately?
I think there some function called pivotCache that allow us to add more than one Pivot table , but how to use it

Comment: are you sure that each PivotTable is placed in new empty range and has new unique name? both are required.

Comment: yes , as you can see , every time I call CreatePivotTable() Function I change the pivotTableName  and the pivotPosition , What I get is one pivot table with the last name passed , last position and with with *ALL* the aggreagtion (it's like all pivote combined in the last one)

Comment: sorry, I can't see that because you do not show arguments which you pass to your method.

Comment: I think there some function called pivotCache that allow us to add more than one Pivot table , but how to use it